# npm nodules for internationalization

Tags: node.js

I am looking for modules that will do Internationalization for `node.js` application for both server side and client side. I tried working with `i18next`. It is working fine with server side, but for client side we need to do some more configuration to work out. but it will load files twice. Can you guys please suggest me the npm modules that work in both client side and server side with minimal configurations(i mean easy to configure) and also better performance. If a better npm module exists dont bother about the minimal configuration that i told, just suggest me. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

10 months after asking this question, I'm writing an answer.

There is [an example](https://github.com/efkan/node-intl-polyfill-example) which needs almost zero configuration.

The example explains that how to implement i18n (also [Intl](https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js) module) on Node.js.

In this example and approach gives the full control to the developer.

On the other hand it shows using Intl module and Translations in all the JS template systems (like EJS, Handlebars etc.).

I hope this helps to someone.